# Angular update view on observable next function

Tags: angular, observable

I have a component which uses a service to obtain data from web api using a get request. Upon result I want to update some variables to show the data on the front end. Although when I console log the output it looks fine, the view doesn't reflect the result.

Markup:

```
<h3>Enquiry Count : {{enquiryCount}}</h3>
```

Component:

```
constructor(private enquiryService: EnquiryService) {}

enquiryCount: number;    

ngOnInit() {                   
  this.enquiryService.getEnquiries().subscribe(n => new function() {
    this.enquiries = n;      
    this.enquiryCount = this.enquiries.length;
  }, e => console.log("error"), () => console.log("complete"));   
 }
```

Comment: is the changeDetection set to OnPush?

Comment: Ill have a look at that @TomaszKula. Not an issue I have had before with promises and Angular 1. thanks

Comment: @Jamlow share the code of your service, currently shared code seems perfect.

Comment: Why the `new function()` in the subscribe? That isn't needed. It is probably part of the problem.

Comment: @AayQue `@Injectable()
export class EnquiryService {
 
  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  getEnquiries():Observable<Enquiry[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Enquiry[]>(apiUrl);    
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

The answer was stated in a comment from the original post. @R.Richards proposed that the new function was causing the issue and it was. Silly of me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `function` in Typescript => it will get you every time!

Answer (score 0):

If you `console.log` the result in subscribe block and see the result, but the template does not update, it's a good sign that it's a changeDetection problem.

Check if your component metadata includes:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush <-- remove this
})
```

If you want to keep the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, you must refactor your `ngOnInit`.

component:

```
enquiryCount$: Observable<number>;    

ngOnInit() {                   
  this.enquiryCount$ = this.enquiryService.getEnquiries()
    .pipe(map(enquires => enquires.length))
}
```

html:

```
<h3>Enquiry Count : {{enquiryCount$ | async }}</h3>
```

Comment: My component isn't set to on push. Its whatever the default is?

Comment: Did you try the async pipe soulution?

Comment: I did, the solution actually was one of the comments made earlier. Thanks for your help!